How to refer an element of a dictionary in data binding when the key is a variable using Vue.js?
I'm using element UI as below. (element-ui version 2.15.14, as Estus Flask remind to add)
<template>
    <el-table :data="DataList" >
      <el-table-column type="expand" >            
            <template #default="props">
              <div>
                <hr>
                <el-table :data="mydict[row.id]" >
                  <el-table-column label="Name" prop="name" />               
                </el-table>
                <hr>
              </div>
            </template>
      </el-table-column>
      
      <el-table-column label="ID">
        <template slot-scope="{row}">
          <span>{{ row.id }}</span>
        </template>
      </el-table-column>
      
    </el-table>
 </template>


export default {
    data() {
        return {
          DataList:[{"id": 1},{"id": 2}],
          mydict:{"1":[{"name": "name1"}, {"name": "name2"}], "2":[{"name": "name3"}, {"name": "name4"}]}
        }
      },
      ......
}  

I want to bind list from mydict by key. When row.id == 1, [{"name": "name1"}, {"name": "name2"}] is used. :data="mydict[row.id]" didn't work. I don't know how to do.

Probably because you have no "row" defined in this scope in the template? Did <span>{{ row.id }}</span> work in another column? Then you're supposed to do the same in this one

@Estus {{ row.id }} can work. I have no idea if the expression of :data="mydict[row.id]" is correct. I'm checking if there're any other simple errors I had missed.

Again, you have no "row" defined. If 

i havent done vue but i tried something like this following the docs

@cmgchess Yes. Your code can work in my project. Thanks.

row seems to be undeclared in the code you posted. I'm glad someone helped you, they may be psychic!

@EstusFlask I don't know it seems there's no "row" definition. I assume it's defined as default name of row in el-table from the lib. In cmgchess's example, there's also no definition of row but works well.

@Wason you can post an answer if u want

@Bravo I don't know clearly about the row definition. But in cmgchess's example, it also works. Is that definition in element-UI module?

@Wason btw refer to the code in this example https://element-plus.org/en-US/component/table#expandable-row . u will get it easily

@Wason Because it uses props.row. You can do template #default="props"> and use props.row, or you can destructure props with <template slot-scope="{row}"> and use rows. There's no magic in el-table, this boils down to vue's slots syntax. The question is also unclear on which version you use. I don't see this documented in element ui (not plus) docs

here is using slot-scope

@cmgchess Any of you can put the answer better than I can. I just read and learn.

@EstusFlask OK. I'm learning about Vue 2 months ago. I'm maintaining an existing project. I need some time to understand your comments.

@Wason Refer the docs https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Named-Slots-Shorthand . There are several syntax variations for slots in Vue 2, which you evidently use. You can stick to the modern one that is used in Vue 3, it would be <template #default="props"> and props.row.id, or destructured props <template #default="{ row }"> and row.id. The point is that "row" couldn't appear out of nowhere if you don't define it

so basically use named slots (#) if using vue3 since slot-scope will be deprecated.
